# MYSQL Community Edition throwing error message continuously in Windows10

Tags: mysql

I'm able to login to database and perform required activities with the root user, Even then following error message is stamped continuously in sql error logs.

[Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Did you set a password on the `root` user? Normally gets installed without one!!

Comment: Yes, I've set and using it to login

Comment: Did you set the password onto `root@localhost` or did you set it on `root@127.0.0.1` or `root@::1`

Comment: Really not sure..I used Windows Installation Package to install MYSQL.

Comment: So how did you set the password on the `root` account

Comment: Well use `phpMyAdmin` or `WorkBench` to reset the password to the same thing for all 3

Comment: Hello @RiggsFolly Have used workbench to rest the password for all 3, still the same issue

Comment: Then are you sure you only have ONE version of MySQL? Could you have MySQL and mariaDB installed?

Comment: I'm running MYSQL 5.7.30 server community edition and workbench 6.3.10 only